# Prefix divisibility

Tags: code-golf, number, integer, division

<sub>[Inspiration](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/32451/66833)</sub>

Given a positive integer \$1 \le n \le 9\$, output all positive \$n\$-digit integers \$i\$ for which the following is true:

- Each digit from \$1\$ to \$n\$ appears exactly once in \$i\$. Therefore, \$i\$'s digits are a permutation of the digits from \$1\$ to \$n\$.
- \$i\$ is divisible by \$n\$
- Removing the rightmost digit from \$i\$ yields another integer \$i_{\text{trunc}(1)}\$ which is divisible by \$n-1\$
- Removing the rightmost digit from \$i_{\text{trunc}(1)}\$ yields another integer \$i_{\text{trunc}(2)}\$ which is divisible by \$n-2\$
- And so on, until \$i_{\text{trunc}(n-1)}\$, which is divisible by 1.

For example, for \$n = 3\$, one such integer is \$321\$, as \$321\$ is divisible by \$3\$, \$32\$ by \$2\$ and \$3\$ by 1.

For \$n = 4, 5, 7\$, there are no such integers. In this case, you may output anything that cannot be confused with a possible output (e.g. `0`, `[]`, nothing, etc.). For \$n = 3, 6\$, you may output the two numbers in any format in which the two numbers are clearly separated from one another.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins.

If you use a lookup table method, brownie points\${}^\dagger\$ are awarded if you also include a version that calculates the correct output.

<sub>\${}^\dagger\$Brownie points may or may not be in the form of an upvote</sub>

### Test cases

These cases are exhaustive, so you will never receive (or have to handle) an input not included here.

```
n -> i
1 -> [1]
2 -> [12]
3 -> [123, 321]
4 -> []
5 -> []
6 -> [123654, 321654]
7 -> []
8 -> [38165472]
9 -> [381654729]
```

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20461/66833)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
LœJʒηāÖP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f5@hkr1OTzm0/0nh4WsD//2YA)

**Commented**:

```python
L         # push [1..n]
 œ        # push all permutations
  J       # join each permutation into a number
   ʒ      # filter those numbers on:
    η     #   each prefix ...
      Ö   #   ... is divisible ...
     ā    #   ... by its index
       P  #   take the product (all)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 68 bytes

```python
lambda n:[`s`[:n]for s in 321654,381654729,123654][380712>>n*2&3::2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7NDoIwEITP7lP0ZMDUhG75bSIvUjcBoyiJLgS4@PTVYjl4@mYymcyM7@UxMLrudHbP9nW5toKNbebGGqZumMQsehYaVZ6lUpceBVZSof4qsrpMCoV1zQfca2OQnO@w70wt32@RkiqJDezGqedFsBRdxLFjcaxFD8rDKgL8CSTQQWnpRwnS1RNkgfmW@z/hF0ER0nLldpOg@vMVfQA)

Outputs a list a strings.

---

**71 bytes**

```python
lambda n:[0,1,12,[123,321],0,0,[123654,321654],0,38165472,381654729][n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BDoJADETP9it6hGRN2C4gkOiPrD1gFCXRQggXv36luJiYHubNNGlnfM@PQSh0x3N4tq/LtUVpfGassWS8JWccWTbZMurKItdgEc1cpXSgH9TshUM3TCjYC06t3G/JcipLG9iNUy8zisEukTQI7k/Yg1XxloG@QAwukjOovyFfPUMRtdz2WgZjGzjEbbXqVoih/vM1fwA)

Just a boring straight hardcode. Outputs a single number, or a list of two numbers, or 0 for no output.

None of the other methods I tried seemed likely to be shorter than this. For instance, one idea is to generate numbers as prefixes of a single number, generating like `123654/10**(6-i)`.

An object method gives the same length. Unfortunately we can't use the much shorter `.pop` because it make the function not reusable because it modifies the list with each call.

```python
[0,1,12,[123,321],0,0,[123654,321654],0,38165472,381654729].__getitem__
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BDoIwEETP7lfsEZLV0BYETPRHsGk8APbgQkgvfn1lsZiYPcybmWQz8zs8J9ZxuN5jV5AipalT2pDRylKxnrhzVUqwimSmEar1D1p7cm7sgw/9y7k4TAsyesblwWOfrT@L/AKHefEckAmHjPPIeLyhByXSKQv6C9qCSWQIZQSUm7dQJT3vvazCNAvq1Dab7ssstH@@tR8)

Aliasing the longest constant also gives the same length:

```python
lambda n,c=381654729:[0,1,12,[123,321],0,0,[123654,321654],0,c/10,c][n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU7LDoJADDzbr@gRkjXSXd4J/sjaA6IoiRZCuPj16y7CwTTpzPQ502d5jqJd31zcq31fby2K6hpTUp6lha5qmyhSpJUlbZTRxCrxEZQfCAUPodadyCe2wq4fZxQcBOdWHvfIrydxDYdpHmTx17GPJHaCxzMOQAEsMegf0QxmY0Zh@AfpqhmyDfO9Hwzg5gCKrVuuuPtnqP50xV8)

Comment: One avenue for improvement might be to use a string like `'0123,321123654,321654381654729'`, which contains every answer, and use magic formulae to slice at the right start and end points. But I don't have the time to explore this right now.

Comment: @Sisyphus Great idea! I took a shot at it and got 75: [TIO](https://tio.run/##VZBbS8NAEIWfnV@xNGCTuKHZay5gIK3V6qOProtEanRBJyX0QX993KQp6MzDdw4DB84cfo4fHfKhvX4ePpuv131DsFwyLqjgTCtJvfQQ@WgyXiwNrnQsr3CVx0yUXb8PFy/rza6uH@snszBoo0QrO7RdTxxxSPoG399CRlkalXBx6B0eiaOkDV0EEBhGOc1o6peN4IpybQ0mzEIwhdfrzc329m53/zCHSwjSb5n@marCWF0KNiBJKuKAjTA@gZ8EtyBmJSjxvSzIyVtQM/X5PlYmp@oWsvmaTzz/wELxzxf2Fw "Python 2 – Try It Online") But there may be room for compression tricks to get it below 71.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>42</sup> 37 bytes

Calculates the numbers.

```
0({:#~0=[:+/#\|])@|:i.@!10&#.\@A.1+i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DTSqrZTrDGyjrbT1lWNqYjUdaqwy9RwUDQ3UlPViHBz1DLUz9f5rcnGlJmfkK2hYp2kqGShogAQtNf8DAA)

- `1+i.` 1…n
- `i.@!…@A.` all possible permutations of 1…n
- `10&#.\` convert every prefix of a permutation to a number
- `0(…)@|:` transpose the matrix and …
- `#\|]` 1…n mod the prefixes, e.g. `1 2 3 | 1 12 123`
- `0=[:+/` sum the result; is it 0?
- `{:#~` then take the last prefix of the permutation (the permutation itself)

Answer (score 3):

## Scala, <s>81</s> 80 bytes

```scala
| =>1.to(|).mkString.permutations.filter{i=>1 to|forall(r=>i.take(r).toInt%r<1)}
```

[Try it in Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/OAhzYdiDSzaHYbcXI4ykNw)

Explanation:

```scala
| =>                          //n, the input
  1.to(|)                     //Range to n
    .mkString                 //Turn it into a string
    .permutations             //Get all permutations
    .filter{ i =>             //Filter them
      1 to | forall(r =>      //For every r from 1 to n
        i.take(r).toInt       //The number made from i's first r digits
          % r < 1             //Should be divisible by r
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 78 bytes

```
(f=FromDigits)/@Select[Permutations@Range[s=#],f@#[[;;k]]~Mod~k~Sum~{k,s}<1&]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tcq7CsIwFADQ3a8QCkWhIPUtNZBB3IRix3CHUNMYYhpIbicxvx6d5G5nOE7iUzmJppdZs7wY2DV4dzHaYFyueKdeqkfRquAm/C0/Rn6Xo1YisgKqgRdCNI0FSDf/SDZ1k0tvW8XPuS6hzG0wI865FjXM/l4Tb4i3xDviPfGB@Eh8gpy/)

-8 bytes from @att

Comment: `\[Divisible]` (`∣`) is shorter than comparing the residue, but we can do even better with `Sum` for [78 bytes](https://tio.run/##Tcq7CsIwFADQ3a8QCkWhIPUtNZBB3IRix3CHUNMYYhpIbicxvx6d5G5nOE7iUzmJppdZs7wY2DV4dzHaYFyueKdeqkfRquAm/C0/Rn6Xo1YisgKqgRdCNI0FSDf/SDZ1k0tvW8XPuS6hzG0wI865FjXM/l4Tb4i3xDviPfGB@Eh8gpy/).

Comment: (straightforward hard-coding gets 74 bytes, though)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>11</s>  10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 thanks to [caird coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833)!

This is a naive method, there could be a more terse one.

```
Œ!JḍḌƤẠƲƇḌ
```

A monadic Link accepting \$n\$ which yields `0` if none are found or a list of valid numbers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJEWvhzt6H@7oObbk4a4FxzYdawey////bwYA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJEWvhzt6H@7oObbk4a4FxzYdawey/1sebn/UtOY/AA).

#### How?

```
Œ!JḍḌƤẠƲƇḌ - Link: n
Œ!         - all permutations of [1..n]
        Ƈ  - filter keep those (p for p in Œ!) for which:
       Ʋ   -   last four links as a monad f(p):
  J        -     range of length = [1..n]
     Ƥ     -     apply to prefixes (of p):
    Ḍ      -       un-decimal
   ḍ       -     divides? (vectorises)
      Ạ    -     all truthy?
         Ḍ - un-decimal
```

Comment: Aside from `Ạ -> P`, this was my exact solution for the test cases :)

Comment: [10 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJEWvhzt6H@7oObYk4NimY@1A1n/Lw@2Pmtb8BwA)

Comment: Yep, nice work @cairdcoinheringaahing - thanks

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) -lm, <s>67</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes

Added 34 bytes to fix a bug kindly pointed out by [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor).
Saved 5 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

```c
f(n){write(1,"321654",n-3&&n-6?0:n);n=n<4?123/exp10(3-n):n>7?381654729/exp10(9-n):n-6?0:123654;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVHbbsIwDH3nK6xKoARa0SRcVkrhYdpXDB5QSKEaBNQirRrtr69zeoECD4uS1rHPObZj6eykLIqQaHr9jqOLIsy2BGeT8ciytSN6Pe1Mlu5MU18Hej5aMi6GKj0zlwhH05leTJfizcCn3KsDXhkoaYjGkJ8Xkb7AcRNpQjvXDuAyDoQreVFb9rmGAK7MBsbNETa45a7opdkkuVte7r8o8Qcl7KNRqlr6R0nuN3Ff7pX8UjEKGSVrlX7wVeq94xlbNrTvwqp54SkGYsqI9FalSHP92pxDEv2oU0hurdJh7enfXT4MBiWeQvU4TVsatSqhATD/FjrHGAyJ1d2CswCsCqfzwEuQZ0ba8uI1CESW4XdCGwHs54mpGFLvcymTr58gvAXhL5BWcd1kpTFHYkPzqEkQKJZl5sfXdeq8kxe/MjxsdknhHI5/)

Total lookup based solution. If there are two solutions: outputs one to `stdout`, and returns the other. If there's only one answer it's simply returned. Returns \$0\$ if there's no answer.

### Bonus round for brownie points

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>232</s> 212 bytes

Saved a whopping 20 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

```c
p;m;j;char b[9],c[9];d;i;f(n){for(d=0,i=n;i;)d+=9*d+i--;for(sprintf(c,"%d",d);d/++i;)if(sprintf(b,"%d",i),qsort(b,n,1,L"\xf06be0f\xd02917beǃ"),!strcmp(b,c)){for(p=0,m=n,j=i;j;j/=10)p|=j%m--;p||printf("%d ",i);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVLLUoMwFN37FZGZzpASpiT4woguHHfO@AFtFzQPTZUUgQVjy8qP86/Em5a@dCFDmJP7OOfmBBE@C9F1Bc/5nIuXrESzcTIlAj5ccsO1b/FSL0pfphExqYUQlkGaDGVgwpC7TFWUxtbaF8QbSI9IzOUoCKDO6F1utskZTN6rRVnD3hJKHr1Jo6OLmYr0pJERS@jlTH19epicVnUp8gLqBN7oF6Cfp5bMUwOTzkcpjXCxSueDHMYoVqteCGSQ0@Ft2@WZsT5eniB4IIlUUyhRK0nHU5SiJSWIMrdigqL1C/Di/GwN4ysK8JLtUdLyP0zsiClmdMsE8H8mZ/dQvCjxqkogckxgyAObNMk9rHOPoMN97PV9YAfy3RjGStVAW8R7eIMq86EW2t8dFY/6yHAf4giux9VjtDFneywLXBuiAFG@Sx1YG96Cu8hiftRXQZ/7UY6jikJ47/maePqrhB2UsD8lvbCioWJ3ng/6A4kn1rt22AECIr1qe9J230K/Zc9VFz7prKq78EM1SlR1Jl5/AA)

Computes the correct numbers through calculation and outputs them to `stdout`. Outputs nothing if there's no answer. Times out on TIO for \$n=9\$ but does all of them in `3m36.499s` on my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 25 bytes

```
ＮθΦＥＸχθＩι⬤…·¹θ›№ιＩλ﹪Ｉ…ιλλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzBCsIwEETvfkWPG6hg8diTBJQeKsU/WGOwgTWbpknFr4/b6mUY5s2MGTEaRiql8yGna37dbYRJtbshOp/g7ChJ0GOAgd/imkNdTaquNM4JnJgTEXTeUJ7dYm/onxaaX@USLa5jzVme3H9DSlDPj0wMW6A/hqweOayVjYoo1ZZyLPuFvg) Link is to verbose version of code. Too slow for `n>5` on TIO. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
ΦＥＸχθＩι
```

List all integers `i` up to `10ⁿ`, such that...

```
⬤…·¹θ
```

... for each integer `l` from `1` to `n`...

```
›№ιＩλ﹪Ｉ…ιλλ
```

`l` is a digit of `i` and the `l`-character prefix of `i` is divisible by `l`.

Slightly faster 28-byte version:

```
ＮθΦＥＸ⊕θθ⍘ι⊕θ⬤…·¹θ›№ιＩλ﹪Ｉ…ιλλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY0xDsIwDEV3TtExkcrAwtIJIoE6FFVwApNabSQ3CWlSxOmDUyYGW5b/e7aeIGgHlHNrfYq3ND8xiJdsdn0wNoqLociLDrzo3Zun1uqAM9qIA2N1VeoMCz4i86MwdfVPSM5PRMWjtJgV72BHFIefeQ0I5b5yiZ@xrGCJgorUuSGRE9tCfTShmpwvyJZyk7LJ@Zj3K30B) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Generates the digits in base `n+1` instead of base `10`, thus making it possible to complete `n=6` on TIO.

Fastest 29-byte version using a compressed lookup table:

```
§⪪”)‴a3HSＧS⸿Dπ¬Z⦄O<ε≔<πUθ8”0Ｎ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMOxxDMvJbVCI7ggJ7NEQ8nYwtDM1MTcyNLA0MDQCIiMY/KMjQwNDEBMoAyYB6QNDGAqlXQUlAyUNHUUPPMKSkv8SnOTUos0NDU1rf//N/uvW5YDAA) Link is to verbose version of code.

Comment: Generating permutations is of course much faster, and can do `n=8` on TIO, but unfortunately takes 40 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3BDsIgDIbvPgXHkuDBi5edlkUTE7csvgEyHMQK26AzPj3Cor206d9@nzJyUV5iSnUIdnRwcQop2FXfpBs1HAS7uIliR6@7XoBzwWZe7XoKBkiwd54ffmFAnG29tY4CzIK1cgIrWCNDhCfPxf4/feaXKG8zaLEuwtlizPQc1m6A00wSA1y1G6OBOSt/oy36GrHwOx@h9QOhh83RfBTqxvjNiuUQi7VK6Zj2K34B "Charcoal – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 15 bytes

```
mdföΛIṠz¦ŀmdḣPḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Pzcl7fC2c7M9H@5cUHVo2dGG3JSHOxYHAPH///@NAQ)

Almost the same as the other question, except with parameters.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 64 bytes

```perl
sub{grep"@_"==y///c,1,12,123,321,123654,321654,$x=38165472,$x.9}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcaBCsIgEIDhVzkOGRvcTtRWjTB6kEAoZizKiStoRM9uE374vzikR5efi/A2z@/L95aGiCeH1i5SyispUnrNkNGFZtttCsvEx5p90U6v5v6XDxDTGF6AwkHbHgH5Po2hRgKkSvhauKZhPAcEPyVQzH3@Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 97 bytes

A recursive function that computes and prints the matching integers.

```javascript
f=(n,s='987654321'.slice(-n),d,p)=>p%d?0:s?[...s].map(v=>f(n,s.replace(v,''),-~d,[p]+v)):print(p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxLDoIwGIT3nuLfmLZpacAngoUbeAHCouGRYLD@aUk3Rq9eq6xmMvPN3LXXrrMTLonPQxgVNcIpcsnPp@Nhv8uIdPPUDTQxTPQCmapw29dp4epGSula@dBIvarG307aAWcdaS8IYSL59KLBlnvGCrSTWSiyMD4tNaAgK8HAFbI0KucMXhuAFSI3RYCDYWWM4u9f1yrad/gC)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 59 bytes

Hard-coding is obviously shorter.

```javascript
n=>[,1,12,[321,123],,,[321654,123654],,q=38165472,q+[9]][n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpBDsIgEEX3PcXsgDA1AmrVikfwAoRFU4vRNINtjRvj2RFcvfdf/qN7d0s/35@vmuJ1SMEmsmeHCpVGZ3Sh8Yh/3203ZWbkMlmzL6XROEl38N6RTyHOnMCCaoHgBGqdKaWATwXQR1riOKzGeOPsYhnI/JHAjgwhcBKirb7pBw)

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##HYpBDsIgEEX3PcXsgDA1AmrVikfwAoRFU4vRNINtjRvj2RFcvfdf/qN7d0s/35@vmuJ1SMEmsmeHCpVGZ3Sh8Yh/3203ZWbkMlmzL6XROEl38N6RTyHOnMCCaoHgBGqdKaWATwXQR1riOKzGeOPsYhnI/JHAjgwhcBKirb7pBw) is perfectly fine for the hardcoding ("you may output anything that cannot be confused with a possible output")

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 71 bytes

```
f[s_:0,l_:0]=0!=##2&&l∣s&&If[l<#,##~f[10s+i,l+1]~i~Do~{i,#},Print@s]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z8tujjeykAnB0jE2hoo2iorG6mp5TzqWFyspuaZFp1jo6yjrFyXFm1oUKydqZOjbRhbl1nnkl9XnamjXKsTUJSZV@JQHKv2P7A0M7UkOi061kHLNTkjv86xqCixss4y9j8A)

Call as `f[][n]`. Prints the results.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
║è[⌐•^∩╖[ª╫√°
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=ba8a5ba9075eefb75ba6d7fbf8&i=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9&m=2)

Same brute force algorithm.  Nothing clever.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 64 bytes

```
=CHOOSE(A1,1,12,"123,321",,,"123654,321654",,38165472,381654729)
```

Input is in `A1`. Hard-coded answer is shorter than calculation would be.

[image: SCreenshot]